# JPA/Spring Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: spring, jpa, one-to-many, transactional

i have a problem whit JPA.

my save method is marked @Transactional like this:

```
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void push(long id) {
            Parent parent = dao.findParentById(id);
            setParentMeta(parent);
            Country country = dao.findCountry(id);
            setParentChild(parent);
            User user = dao.findUser(id);
            dao.update(parent);
        }

        public void setParentMeta(Parent parent){
            parent.setTitle("toto");
            parent.setdescription("some description");
        }

        public void setParentChild(Parent parent){
            List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String date : dao.getList()) {
                Child child = new Child();
                ChildPK childPK = new ChildPK();
                childPK.setProductId(parent.getId());
                childPK.setDate(date);
                child.setChildPK(childPK);
                child.setParent(parent);
                childList.add(child);
            }
            parent.setChildList(childList);
        }
```

My parent entity :

```
        public class Parent {
            ...
            private long parentId;
            @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
            private List<Child> childList;
            ...
        }
```

My Child entity :

```
        public class Child {
            ...
            @EmbeddedId
            protected ChildPK childPK;
            @MapsId("parentId")
            @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "parent_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
            private Parent parent;
            ...
        }
        @Embeddable
        public class ChildPK {
            ....
            @Basic(optional = false)
            @Column(name = "parent_id")
            private long parentId;
            @Basic(optional = false)
            @Column(name = "date")
            @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            private Date date;
            ....
        }
```

my problem is when i delete @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) from method "push" and put it in the dao all insert/update or rallback work perfectly :

```
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public E update(E entity) {
            return entityManager.merge(entity);
        }
```

but if i put this annotation in push methode and delete it from dao i get this exception:

```
        Duplicate entry '3623238-2016-02-21 00:00:00' for key 'PRIMARY'
        Error Code: 1062
        Call: INSERT INTO child (date, parent_id) VALUES (?, ?)
            bind => [2016-02-21 00:00:00.0, 3623238]
```

The problem here is eclipselink flush automacticly when child change.
there are a why to flush at the end of push method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
the transaction manger is not well configured here is [the solution with code example](http://www.threadstuck.com/question/jpaspring-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary/)

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when you are trying to persist object already exist, on the other hand, @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) use the already opened transaction and open new one when there is no one opened, I think the problem with **findByParentId** method, so try to "find" it and then send it the **push** method.

Comment: i cant put findByParentId outside push method

Comment: please clarify why you can not do that?

Comment: because that changes any things there are also some find case just below, the problem here is if I delete all find and call directly update that work. and for my treatment I need to do find before saving

Comment: here you need to save new Childs for existing Parent?

Comment: Please check if the column (ID) in child table is auto_increment

Comment: you can use Propagation.REQUEST_NEW which means that a new transaction will open regardless the existing one